# What is the name of the diagram in this question? How do you read it?

Tags: orbitals

[image]

My teacher calls it an 'orbital diagram' but every time I search for information something completely different pops up. I assumed it was a fancy Bohr diagram, but the electron placement is always weird. I understand electron configuration , but I cannot understand why each electron goes where on this diagram. This example is really simplistic, but other ones that I've seen make no sense in terms of electron placement.

Answer (score 5):

So, Bohr's diagram is a super-simplified version of this, almost to the point where it is arguably incorrect.

This diagram, which shows the *orbitals* of an electron, shows where an electron has a >90% chance to be. That means that if an electron is in any of the orbitals in your picture there, and you take many snapshots of the atom, it will show a higher concentration inside the orbital. You will find quite a few outside the orbital, but the biggest concentration will be inside those "bubbles".

Basically it shows where you are *most likely* to find the electrons around an atom.

If you google "different orbitals" you will find picture similar to that of yours. (I tried just now). Hope that clears most of it up, if not I really reccommend you to watch Khan Academy's videos on the subject. That really helped me.